# Solenoid switching damaging MOSFET transistor

Tags: mosfet, solenoid, flyback

I have a system where multiple electromagnets/solenoids are switched with a high-side MOSFET switching circuit. The switching circuit diagram is as follows:
[image: MOSFET switching circuit]

As seen from the circuit diagram, the solenoid is switched with an NMOS-PMOS transistor pair configuration, and the control signal comes from a 74HC595 shift register. The NMOS transistor (Q25) is the BSS138L, which has a maximum drain current of 200 mA. The PMOS transitor (Q110) is the DMP2305U, which has a maximum continuous drain current of 4.2 A. All transistors are in SOT-23 package. The solenoid has a resistance of 75 Ohms and draws approximately 150-250 mA of current when switched on. The flyback diode (D25) is the 1N4007. The wires from the switching circuit to the actual terminal of the solenoid vary in length from between 2 to 10 meters. No additional flyback diodes exist at the solenoids, nor is it practically possible to get to the solenoid to add such diodes there (due to the design of the current system). Therefore, they exist on the switching side of the circuitry.

What occasionally happens is the following: After the solenoid has been commanded to switch off, it occasionally stays "stuck" in the on position, even though the output from the 74HC595 is off ("low"). The LED in the diagram is there to indicate what the switching state of the circuit is at any given time. In this case, this LED also remains on, which indicates that (at the very least) the PMOS transistor is still conducting. When the solenoid is commanded to switch on again, the NMOS transistor burns out (with a rather spectacular glow) and the 74HC595 gets fried. The PMOS transistor seems to still be fine, although I wouldn't count on it.

It has been pointed out to me that the flyback diode is probably too slow in dissipating the inductive kickback caused by switching off the solenoid. This can certainly be replaced by a Schottky diode for faster dissipation of the inductive kickback.

The fact that the NMOS transistor and 74HC595 gets damaged suggests that there is probably 12-15 VDC (from VCC) ending up at the output of the 74HC595 (and thus at the gate of the NMOS transistor), which conflicts with the 5 VDC power supply of the 74HC595 and eventually damages the IC. My guess is that what is possibly happening is that the flyback diode cannot dissipate the inductive kickback fast enough and that a large enough voltage differential occurs at the source terminal that damages the internal diode of the PMOS transistor as well as the transistor itself, and essentially short-circuits the gate terminal with the drain/source. Now that this happened, there is a very low resistance path from VCC to the drain terminal of the NMOS transistor via the gate of the PMOS transistor. In addition, there is then also a constant low resistance path between VCC and the solenoid, since the transistor constantly conducts at this stage. When the NMOS transistor gets switched on, it essentially short-circuits VCC with GND (via the NMOS transistor) and damages the NMOS transistor, causing a similar gate-drain/source short-circuit path that ends up at the 74HC595.

In order to prevent current from flowing into the PMOS transistor due to the inductive kickback, I thought of putting a diode in series with its source terminal (D86 in the below schematic). In addition, a low-ohm resistor (R92 in the below schematic) in series with the flyback (Schottky) diode could also help in dissipating the inductive kickback faster. This brings us to the following schematic:[image: Updated switching circuit]

Does my analysis make sense/does it seem plausable? Does it sound like a good solution to the problem?

For what it is worth, this question is related to [another earlier question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295086/intermittent-mclr-reset-on-pic32-involves-switching-electromagnets) I posted but focuses on a separate issue. The issue in my other post and this issue are most likely related in some ways, but I would like to focus on each issue separately. Many thanks to those who already contributed to the other post.

Your help would be greatly appreciated in this regard. 
Thank you in advance.

=======================================================

**UPDATE:**

Taking into account all of the comments and advice given, I have updated the switching circuit to include the following:

- Schottky flyback diode (D1) ([SS110](http://za.rs-online.com/web/p/products/9179149/) in SMA package) instead of the 1N4007
- Resistors at NMOS gate (R93) as well as between NMOS drain and PMOS gate/gate pull-up resistor node (R92)
- Bypass capacitor between VCC and GND near the PMOS transistor (C1)
- A suitably spec'ed PMOS transistor (Q86) with *Vgs,max* = ±20 V (the [DMG2307L](http://za.rs-online.com/web/p/products/8222539/), the previously used PMOS transistor is the [DMP2305U](http://za.rs-online.com/web/p/products/7514256/) with *Vgs,max* = ±8 V).

This leads to the following circuit:
[image: Updated switching circuit]

A few questions now arise:

1. The newly chosen PMOS transistor (DMG2307L) has a higher gate threshold voltage (3 V) than the older one (0.9 V). In the original circuit there was no voltage divider at the gate of the PMOS transistor, which lead to gate voltages exceeding the maximum rating of the transistor. Now the new transistor has a higher *Vgs,max* which is higher than the supply voltage of the circuit, although I would like to still design in a precaution that the PMOS transistor gate never experiences a voltage too high. Therefore the resistor R92 is added in the above circuit. What would be a suitable resistor choice for limiting the gate voltage to 5 V (which should fully turn on the transistor, given its threshold voltage of 3 V)? Is it really necessary to have R92 if the transistor can handle the expected gate voltages, as if R92 wasn't there (i.e. VCC)? **UPDATE** - *Yes, this resistor is requred. The initial placement of R92 was incorrect. It is now moved between Q1's gate and the node connecting R7/Q86's gate.*
2. Is the addition of capacitor C1 a wise idea? Will it help in suppressing any possible voltage spikes that could occur during switching? If so, what would be a suitable value? **UPDATE** - *Yes, this capacitor is required. Values of 220 uF, 470 uF and 1000 uF will be tried/tested.*
3. Is the Schottky diode (D1) choice a suitable one for this application, especially given it is in SMA package? **UPDATE** - *Yes, it is suitable for this use.*

Comment: I had suggested 1,000UF cap at the MOSFET switches. Have you done that?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, what's the idea of putting the big cap across the solenoid? Is it just for fault-finding? It'd obviously affect the solenoid switch-on/off times and put strain on the PSU.

Comment: Let me be clearer: is the 12-15volt VDD heavily bypassed to the Diodes anodes? As the PFETs turn off, the sharp movement low on the drains will couple thru the bulk to sources, and jerk down on the sources; that movement, which is the 12--15volts, couples thru PFET Cgate into drain of NFET, and thru NFET drain-gate to the shift-register.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, sorry it's not much clearer at all. But I can decode it as: put a 1000uF capacitor across the supply, close to the FETs. (You also think that when the output FET is switched on, the voltage transition on Q110 source (from GND to 12..15V) will couple through the Cgs of Q110 then the Cdg of Q25 and onto the shift register output. Can't see how that would burn out the FETs but...)

Comment: Whatever the larger problem here, you should have series resistors between each FET gate drive and the FET gate itself. Try 470 R. You have to remember that the gate presents a capacitive load to what's driving it. So when driving low-to-high, your logic gate has a capacitor across it acting as an instantaneous short circuit. When driving low, it's trying to short a charged capacitor. The resistor limits the current between the driver and the FET gate. Do the same for both FETs.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf: I haven't updated the hardware with your suggestion yet. I have to have as much done beforehand as possible before being able to test it again on the actual system due to traveling and cost issues. I will, however, add your suggestion to the reviewed design.

Comment: @TonyM: I am still a bit uncertain about how the coupling through the FET capacitances happen/work. As far as I understand it, there is a very high resistance at the FETs' gates which should limit current flow to/from the gates to a negligibly small current. Furthermore, a capacitor acts as an open circuit for DC current. Does the coupling through the capacitances happen due to the quick change in voltage being "seen" as a momentary AC signal, thus allowing the capacitances to conduct? I am a bit lost at understanding how current flows between the FET driver and the FET gate...

Comment: That's a question for @analogsystemsrf, I just tried to translate his comment and I don't think capacitive coupling is the problem. It's true that FETs act like they have capacitors between each of their three terminals, with Cgs and Cdg being most important here. I'd put capacitance aside and get the right FET in there: see Andyaka's answer and, more importantly, my comments. You do need gate series resistors too, as I've said - have you put them in? Cheers.

Comment: @TonyM: No I haven't put those series resistors in at the FET gates yet. It is just something I am not used to doing. But if we "put capacitance aside", why do we still need the resistors at the FET gates? Aren't they there to account for the capacitances? Or am I understanding you wrong?

Comment: Series resistors are a must. I recommended putting capacitive coupling aside as a source of your FET failures, but not the loading effects of gate capacitance as a source of damage to the logic gate. Sorry if that was unclear though I did state them separately. Fixing a circuit will mean removing every one of the faults. Your circuit needs a redesign, I'm afraid. You up for it?

Comment: @TonyM the HCxxx CMOS has high enough ESR and lower Coss of than Ciss of MOSFET so no Rg needed

Comment: @TonyM 74HC595 @ 4.5Vdd.... Vol/Iol=0.15V(typ)/4mA = 38 Ω or 0.33Vmax/4mA = 82 Ω

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, I hear you and I do see and know the numbers :-) I would still use a series gate resistor and will always encourage others to do so as routine from logic gates of all families. We don't design circuits that work, we design circuits that never don't work. Ample decoupling is also a good habit rather than an absolute requirement calculated precisely to the needs of each specific circuit. There's a good few others. Put the 0.5p resistor in and change a low chance of long-term failure into a zero chance. That's my considered view on it and I appreciate yours :-)

Comment: OK @TonyM I'm sold on Gate R's .  The miller cap pulse feedback is bidirectional from Drain to Gate and the transient noise on this cable could be ground shift for all we know.  Time for the OP to do some serious Diff Probe scope measurements or get a big CM ferrite sleeve.

Comment: @TonyM: I am certainly up for redesigning the circuit. As you said, we want circuits that never don't work :) The only thing that I am keeping in mind is that whatever I change on the switching circuitry will have to be repeated another 79 times, since I have 80 of those solenoids that I am switching. So I would like to redesign the circuit as efficiently but also as robust as possible. I will put in those gate resistors and will start with using the 470 ohm as per your suggestion.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: I have a very strong feeling that there is ground shift happening in this circuit and that it is the cause of my other issue mentioned in my question (intermittent PIC reset). I guess the noise on the long cables is a very probable cause for this ground shift and possibly adds to the inductive kickback occurring during switching. As stated earlier, one option would be to add flyback diodes directly at the solenoids, but this is not practically possible due to their locations. So I have to account for that noise on some other way.

Comment: **comment continues**: As I mentioned in my comment to @TonyM I will have to repeat any changes to the design 79 more times, so I am trying to avoid too "bulky"/"expensive" changes to the design. Unfortunately I do not have access to a scope and access to the system is limited due to traveling distances (about 250 km). However, if some changes are inevitable, then it has to be done. I am just trying to include as much as possible in the redesign before having to go out to the site again. Besides the ferrite sleeve, what other options are there to handle the noise on the long cables?

Comment: STP cables with low IR drop, small area loop between V+0V and switched output with diode mounted near source and very low ESR cap across V+,0V and ensure ground current for PIC is not shared by solenoid. i.e. separate wires. **first verify if it is conducted loss, induced spike on ground rails or radiated noise.** Did you understand the red blue arrows in my schematic? this is a must.

Comment: Good luck with the fixes :-) From reading it all, I'd definitely recommend: better FET (Vgs(max) +/-20V); 10 K resistor between Q25's drain and R31/Q110-gate; 470 R between the 74HC595 and Q25 gate; no zener (not needed); bulk capacitors across supply near Q110 or solenoid connector.

Comment: @TonyM: Thanks, it seems I will need it :) I agree with all your recommendations. Regarding the bulk capacitors, should there be such a capacitor for every solenoid's output? What specifications should such a capacitor have?

Comment: Can't say, I'm afraid - I don't know (a) your solenoid part, power supply, existing decoupling and PCB/cabling distances. You could trial-and-error it or calculate it. Former is: try a 220, 470 and 1000 uF, stick a scope across your solenoid output then your supply by the FET and look at the rail noise and sag during the fastest solenoid operations. For the latter, we need (a) :-)

Comment: @TonyM: I am a bit reluctant to do trial-and-error, since I will have to repeat whatever changes I make a lot of times to be consistent. So let's rather go with option (a) - the electromagnets have a resistance of 75 ohm and draws about 190-250 mA of current, the power supply is 14.5 VDC. The only decoupling caps currently are those around the MCU, which is on a separate PCB from where the switching circuitry lies. The switching circuitry (together with 74HC595) is on its own PCB, with ribbon cables between these PCBs for controlling the 74HC595 ICs. Cables to solenoids are between 2-10 m.

Comment: @TonyM: I have updated the design with some of the recommended changes and updated the question together with these changes. Some new questions are also included in the question update. Kindly have a look at it, please.

Comment: (1) yes; (2) yes; (3) yes. I commented on R92 and C1 at length already, can't go over that again but you have R92 in the wrong place. Kindly re-read and move R92.

Comment: @TonyM: Thanks for your answer. I realise that I have misinterpreted the placement of R92. I have updated the circuit (I hope it is correct now). Just a quick question on this - If Q1 is off, wouldn't the gate voltage at Q86 still be VCC (R92 will be "floating")? If Q1 is on, R92 will form a voltage divider at Q86's gate, which will still cause a gate voltage higher than the threshold voltage of Q86 (if R92 = 10k as per your suggestion), causing Q86 to still not conduct when it should. What is the purpose of R92 in this configuration? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Hi, please can you contact me in chat now if you're able :-)

Answer (score 4):

> Does my analysis make sense/does it seem plausable? Does it sound like
>   a good solution to the problem?

No, because it doesn't address the basic design flaw....

The DMP2305U P channel MOSFET has a maximum voltage rating between gate and source of +/- 8 volts: -

[image]

You appear to be hitting it with anything from 12 volts to 15 volts. This will likely puncture the gate-source region and cause the knock-on effects you describe.

As with any new device you choose always read the data sheet for the maximum ratings.

Comment: @wave.jaco, the missing bit in Andyaka's correct answer is the fix: you can put a 10 K resistor between Q25's drain and R31/Q110-gate. If your 12..15 V rail spec is accurate, the Q110 Vgs will be restricted to -6..-7.5 V. Don't forget to put a 470 R series resistor between the 74HC595 and Q25 gate.

Comment: @TonyM I would not recommend this. I would want to know the full range of the 12V to 15V power supply voltage and either go for choosing a P channel MOSFET with adequate rating or add a series 2k2 to 4k7 resistor where you suggest AND have a 5.6 volt zener across R31.

Comment: Yes, you're right, a higher spec FET is a better idea. I did put the condition on the rail being accurate. Personally, I don't put zeners in with these low currents, the actual drop can be a volt or two higher until you're in the mA's of their graph. But a FET with Vds(max) of +/-20 V driven from a potential divider looks favourite to me. If you edit your answer with a proposed solution, I'll upvote.

Comment: @TonyM I'm done with this question now. The guy asked for an analysis and I told him he needed to fix the design flaw. Job done!

Comment: @Andyaka: Thank you for pointing that out, I did not realize that. I will certainly choose a higher spec'ed PMOS transistor. The 12-15 V power supply is accurate. To be precise, the current system has a power supply of around 14.5 VDC. I specified 12-15 V just to cover any variance on subsequent installations. Regarding the your suggestion for the Zener diode, do you mean it should be in parallel with R31, and with the cathode to the PMOS side or to the NMOS side? Sorry if it sounds trivial, but I want to make 100% sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes in parallel with R31 like my answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/205850/logic-level-p-channel-mosfet-switch

Comment: @Andyaka: Thanks for the answer regarding the Zener diode. So in essence will it limit the gate voltage of the PMOS transistor to the Zener voltage, i.e. 5.6 V in the case of your suggestion, or rather (12 V - 5.6 V) = 6.4 V? I think I understand that the principle of your suggestion is to limit the voltage at the PMOS transistor gate if the transistor is not spec'ed for the full 12 V, as is the case currently with my under-spec'ed transistor.

Comment: When we say gate voltage, it is a loose term that more strictly means gate-source voltage. If a zener protects a pmos device and the source is positive gate voltage means from gate to positive source i.e. exactly the same as gate to 0 volt on an nmos device.

Comment: @Andyaka: Thanks for the clarification. I realize that I have been confusing the drain and source with each other for the PMOS transistor, due to its orientation in my schematic. I have looked at some readily available transistors, and it seems that the DMG2307L should do the job: max gate-source voltage = ±20 V, max drain-source voltage = -30 V, max drain current = -2.5 A. Besides these parameters, is there anything else I should be looking at in the PMOS transistor specs?

Comment: I think you have it covered, just calculate max power dissipation based on possible worst case on-resistance and that should cover it. If you were using pwm to control the solenoid then switching losses should be taken into account but, I don't think you are using pwm.

Comment: @Andyaka: I am currently busy with making the changes to the circuit. What crossed my mind now was the LED that I have in the circuit. What is not shown in my schematic is that the LED connection is terminated with a 10k resistor to ground (it is a very bright SMD LED). Its sole purpose is to indicate the state of the switching circuit. Do you think its current placement could be contributing to any of the effects that we are trying to prevent?

Comment: There's only one problem and that is the 8 volt rating.

Comment: @Andyaka: I have updated the design with some of the recommended changes and updated the question together with these changes. Some new questions are also included in the question update. Kindly have a look at it, please.

Comment: @wave.jaco Sorry but this question is evolving too much. You have my original answer and that was your problem. I don't have anything more to add. In future you should try and ensure that question evolution is somewhat more limited than what you currently have.

Comment: @Andyaka: No problem. You did point out a critical flaw in the design; one that I should've looked at in the first place. I have certainly learned a lot with this exercise. Thank you for all your assistance with the question.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you asking a brand new question about the new transistor and its suitability for driving the load (did you specify the load sufficiently, I can't recall?) and avoiding too much heat dissipation. I personally had no problem with the original diode. It's slow on reverse recovery but that doesn't mean it's unsuitable for this application at all. You won't see any significant voltage spikes during switching but it's always a good idea to add a decoupler just in case.

Answer (score 0):

### RECOMMENDATIONS

- Scrap existing design and use more robust Allegro A2982 8 Channel 500mA non-inverting BJT drivers and allow 1.7V drop for choosing V+
- Include low ESR decoupling cap on board.
- Use CM choke on all IO cables or SMT CM choke on board ( low cost)
- use TP or STP cables for all I/O.
- Isolate Out cables from any sensor cables.
  [image]

### previous answer and comments

{ in addition to @Andy_aka 's fine answer}

I have 4 design suggestions;

- a) improper clamp diodes b) Vds & Vgs violation from negative spike , c) simplification, d) Pulse loop current noise.

  - In general, put power diode across output to ground for high side driver in reverse polarity so negative spike clamps voltage with diode when turned off. It must handle same current as switch but shorter duration determined by L/DCR

**. - you don't need a series diode, just a reverse shunt , D25 to gnd on output.**

- you also don't want R92 , it only creates a -ve spike

  - **otherwise your exceed Vds absolute MAX of -20V on Q110 with a LARGE negative spike turning off the solenoid faster.**. (in andy's datasheet)
- if you used just a simple low side Nch power driver with RdsOn ~1 ohm, it would work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffoL1y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I stretched schematic only for purposes here to illustrate a point ( as much as practical) that dv/dt and dI/dt generate E and H field EMI from antenna effects.

- 74HCxxx logic @ 5V is roughly equivalent to a voltage source with a 100 Ohm gate resistor.

Comment: Can you flip that voltage source the right way? Drives me mad. Thanks in advance!

Comment: sure , sorry, It was intentional to simulate a power source off board but wires close together.  ( i was using an illogical represent to try and illustrate a physical twisted pair not possible here ;)  Students often have inductive pigtails and no decoupling caps with a Big Loop Antenna and wonder why they have glitches.

Comment: Thanks. I got the distance part. But without reading everything in detail, isn't it just the inductive kickback from the relay coil itself which kills OPs MOSFET?

Comment: Andy told him about 1 stage overvoltage on 2nd gate. I added kickback part on -Vds overvoltage and then it can be simplified to 1 NchFet and watch out for transient loops for EMI

Comment: @wave.jaco are you getting this?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: Thanks Tony. I see from your circuit that you changed the design from switching 12 V to the electromagnet (where it was always grounded), to switching ground to the electromagnet (where it is always connected to 12 V). I understand that this is a much easier way of switching, but due to the way the electromagnets are connected I cannot change their common polarity from common-negative to common-positive. It is actually a design spec that the electromagnets must remain common negative. That is the whole reason why I am using the high-side NMOS-PMOS switching circuit.

Comment: now you tell us (lol) ok They make **high side switches**  for cars by the billions with better features and low cost FYI with logic inputs ) (don't reinvent the wheel)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: My apologies for only mentioning it explicitly now :) I did not know you get those high side switches you are talking about. I will have a look into those.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: I have updated the design with some of the recommended changes and updated the question together with these changes. Some new questions are also included in the question update. Kindly have a look at it, please.

Comment: @wave.jaco it seems you do not understand my answer for if you did you would never have mutual coupling and lack of decoupling on driver board. YOu blew your CMOS because of this I would scrap your driver design in favour of proper high drivers with proper decoupling and proper CM noise rejection and differential crosstalk to signal to driver. Sorry but you have too many blunders

Comment: nor would you even think of adding Series R to shunt diode and adding C reduces slew rate but with resonance.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: I am sure that I understood your answer and i am aware that you advised against the series resistor at the flyback diode. I just asked about it again in general after I have made changes to the design. However, it is clear that this is a bad idea, so I will leave that as well as the capacitor out (I have removed that part of the question update).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of the A2982 driver IC. It certainly seems like an ideal replacement of the switching circuit, and certainly much less trouble to use/design around. Perhaps I should rather consider using it instead. However, I must say that it would be satisfactory to get the switching circuit right and properly working. I know it is much more tedious than just using a driver IC, but I want to completely understand what I did wrong and get it right. I do not give up that easily :) Besides, my initial PMOS transistor choice was a fatal flaw in the design from the very start.

Comment: you will need to understand the RF coupling differences between your design and mine to see why it will still fail, suggested by the flow of arrows for each step pulse edge from the hidden parasitics not shown on schematic